# TypeORM Column default to Postgres lastval()

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

How to set the default of a column using a Postgres function? "lastval()" is a Postgres function that takes the latest database id. I need to add to it for my column's default value, which is derived off the database id. I've tried different syntax's but am unsure how to do it. Here are the postgres docs detailing the functions:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html#FUNCTIONS-SEQUENCE-TABLE

```
function formatter(val) {
return String("PREFIX" + val + "111").slice(0,6)
}

@Column (default: formatter("nextval()")
userID: string
```

thanks!

Comment: No you don't. From the docs:  *It is an error to call lastval if nextval has not yet been called in the current session. This function requires USAGE or SELECT privilege on the last used sequence.*

Comment: You are better off using ```nextval()```. Did you try this way, ```@Column ({default: () => nextval()} )```?

Comment: i can change it to nextval() but id run into the exact same problem still. the problem is recognizing this as a database function vs a string. thanks for pointing it out tho! i will edit the question with nextval()

Comment: @vicki , yes I did try that, and that worked in putting the database id (so the @ PrimaryGeneratedColumn postgres id into the 'userId' column by default, but my issue is that i'm trying to add more to it. I'm trying to get that nextval() and append a prefix or suffix to it

Comment: If you want a generated ID, use an `identity` column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name could you point me to the docs for identity columns? seems like a good idea

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

Comment: can't figure out how to use it in this context :)

Comment: There is a ```BeforeInsert``` hook in typeorm where I think you modify certain attributes. Look into that one as well.

Comment: @vicki, that won't work either because the .id i am trying to append to it isn't accessible if i do 

@ BeforeInsert
def function() {
this.userId = "PREFIX" + this.id
}

this.id isn't accessible. the only time I can access the id is with "lastval()" but in that way I can't append more to it :(